# Sample points around a unit sphere without repetition

Tags: python

I would like to sample points around the surface of a unit sphare without repetition in python. phi - [0-2pi] and theta [0, pi]

I have this code:

```
def get_random_angles(n):
    phis = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, n)
    thetas = np.arccos(1 - np.random.uniform(0, 2, n))
    
    return thetas, phis
```

How can I make sure the generated numbers do not reapeat?

Comment: The probability that two points are equal is 0 (or extremely close to 0 since the computer random numbers have a finite number of digits). Hence no need to check for that.

Comment: If you absolutely wanted to verify that no phi-theta pair is repeated, you could put the zipped results into a set, and verify the length of the set matches n.  If not, then generate n - len(set) additional angles, check that for repeats, and then merge the results.  However, as RandomGuy said, the probability of repeats is so low its probably not worth checking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 options I can think of:

1. you can pre-generate non-redundant coordinates to a suitable precision and use the `sample` function from  the `random` built-in library
2. you can save the coordinates to a list and do `if coord in coord_list` conditional before adding to the list
3. you can use a `set()`, which cannot contain any duplicate objects, i.e. `set(1,1,2,3,4,4,5)` becomes `{1,2,3,4,5}`.

Given your function though, I think the number of repetitions will be negligible unless you're generating a lot of coordinates.

Applying the most performant option (3) to your code would look something like:

```
import numpy as np

def get_random_angles(n):
    phis = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, n)
    thetas = np.arccos(1 - np.random.uniform(0, 2, n))
    while l := len(set(zip(thetas,phis))) != n:
        t,p=get_random_angles(n-l)
        np.concatenate(thetas,t)
        np.concatenate(phis,p)
    return thetas, phis
```

Comment: (3) has a performance advantage over (2), since checking for the presence of an item in an N-element list is O(N), whereas in the corresponding set it's O(1).

Comment: The `set` approach seems interesting. Is there a one-liner to make work with the current function? Such that the size `n` is mantained?

Comment: Assuming that you're looking for unique pairs of `thetas` and `phis`, it would be something like `set(zip(thetas, phis))`, otherwise `set(thetas)` and `set(phis)`. My strategy would be to add that to the end of the function and check its length. If the length < n, then generate n minus length new coordinates, update the set, and check again, repeat if necessary, and return when length == n. For set documentation see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Comment: This worked.  I will post the final version

Answer (score 1):

Something like this did the trick:

```
def get_random_angles(n):

    result=set()

    while len(result) < n:
        phi = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, size=n-len(result))
        theta = np.arccos(1 - np.random.uniform(0, 2, size=n-len(result)))
        new_tuples = set(zip(theta, phi))
        result.update(new_tuples)

    return result
```

Comment: This will only attempt to reach `n` values one extra time. In my edited answer, there's a recursive while loop that will guarantee the function outputs `n` coordinates

Comment: sorry, but I did not get it. What do you mean by one extra time?

Comment: On second look, I was wrong. Your function is recursive too, so it will continue to run until you get the right number—my bad! The if statement, `if (length is not n)` should be tweaked to `if length != n`, though. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is) for an explanation as to why.

Comment: It's recursive, but the recursive calls don't update the caller's set object - they just return their result to the caller to update its set. So the code does indeed have the problem you identified @bc1155

Comment: I redid the implementation. Now it should be OK